# General php function for multiple forms

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a small application in which i have 9 different forms, and every form have a least 40+ fields where the user must enter some data.

I have written each form in a single php file and made a master PHP file where i only add the form in the middle of the page.

My question is:

I don't want to write 9 different function for each form coz it would be too long and i don't think it's the best practice, so is there a way or idea that can help me make a general function in which i can pass some variables to and add the data to the db.

Can i like iterate through the $_POST array and extarct the data and reformat it somehow?
but then again every field have a different name and i seems like this is impossible to do.

Comment: "I don't want to write 9 different function for each form", what are you doing with these functions?

Comment: "adding data" to the data base, because every form have different fields from each other i want to make a general one for handling the input

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
<?php

abstract class FormData
{
    const BOOLEAN = 'bool';
    const INTEGER = 'int';
    const FLOAT = 'float';
    const STRING = 'string';
    protected $_types = array();

    public static function create($data)
    {
        $action = isset($data['action']) ? $data['action'] : '';
        switch ($action)
        {
            case 'form1': return new MyForm1($data);
            default: return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected function loadPostVars($data)
    {
        foreach ($data AS $var=>$value)
        {
            $value = $this->convertVar($var, $value);
            if (!is_null($value) && property_exists($this, $var))
            {
                $this->$var = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    protected function convertVar($var, $value)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($var, $this->_types))
        {
            $type = $this->_types[$var];
            switch ($type)
            {
                case FormData::BOOLEAN: return (bool)(int)$value;
                case FormData::INTEGER: return (int)$value;
                case FormData::FLOAT: return (float)$value;
                case FormData::STRING: // drop down
                default:
                    return myEscapeString($value);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class MyForm1 extends FormData 
{
    public $fld1;
    public $fld2;
    public $fld3;
    // etc...

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->_types = array(
            'fld1' => FormData::INTEGER,
            'fld2' => FormData::STRING,
            'fld3' => FormData::BOOLEAN,
        );
        $this->loadPostVars($data);
    }
}

// And finally process your form data
// You should add hidden input 'action' to each form to identify the form
if ($form = FormData::create($_POST))
{
    echo $form->fld1, $form->fld2, $form->fld3;
}
else 
{
    exit('error: unknown action provided');
}

?>
```

This solution has to be improved - I've written it very fast. But I hope you'll catch the main idea. Hope this will help. Sure, in each form class you can add specific methods to process the request etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in something like [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html).

Comment: thanx for is there anyother way? i'm not very familiar with ZF and i started reading about it just a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I've used something similar in one of my projects. Basically, I define all the fields, including how to display them, what data type they have (number, date, etc), as well as what to do with them once posted back. Then you pass that information to one function which generates a HTML form. When that form is submitted, you pass the same information to a different function which performs the necessary tasks.

In my specific case, it was just used to create search forms, so the processing involved creating a SELECT sql statement. Here's a sample of one of the field definitions:

```
$criteria = array(
    array("label" => "Search clients",
          "type"  => "radio",
          "values"=> array("1" => "Just " . $client->getName(),
                           "2" => "All clients"),
          "where" => array("1" => "c.`clientId` = " . $client->getId(),
                           "2" => "1"), // always true
          "default" => "1"),
    array("label" => "Last Name",
          "type"  => "text",
          "where" => "s.`lastName` LIKE '%s'"),
    array("label" => "First Name",
          "type"  => "text",
          "where" => "s.`firstName` LIKE '%s'")
    // etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 small thoughts..

1) Do you show all 9 forms in one page? If yes - I reeeally don't think it's a good idea.
2) Why don't you divide your forms to different pages and give same names to fields on your forms where it is possible?

Comment: no, each form is displayed on the separate page, i only want to make a general function for adding data without having to repeating code

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on the $_POST array with a foreach.

```
   foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
      echo $name, ' ', $value, '<br />';
   }
```

Comment: While you can do this, it's a really dangerous way to write SQL queries.

Comment: @acrosman

You can store potentially harmful data inside your database but you have to be careful when you display it back on your website.

Answer (score 0):

As SleepyCod said, your breast bet is operating a `foreach`, but the answer needs to be expanded upon:

- Are the form fields equivalent to the table?
- Is each form being used to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` into more than table?

The reason I ask is because this is something that I've done for my webpage. I created a dynamic form structure where the table is queried in question, the schema is retrieved and a `foreach` + `switch()` is used to determine WHAT the field is to be used.

But that's not what you're asking.

So, instead, I give you:

```
// Assuming one table:one form, and each input-name = column name.

//strip array $_POST into its key and value.
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
 $vals .= "'$val', ";
 $keys .= "`$key`, ";
}

// Lest we want to generate errors, shave off the trailing comma and whitespace.
$keys_strip = substr($keys, 0, -2);
$vals_strip = substr($vals, 0, -2);
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO t1 ($keys_strip) VALUES ($vals_strip)");
```

For multiple tables, it got a bit trickier. I'd opt for using a quick identify at the beginning of each form, so we can do the following:

```
// Assuming two+ table:one form, for each input, name='t1:column_name'; assume tables are defined in an array per form for easy reference.

//strip array $_POST into key and value, then separate the key into two separate fields. This will ONLY work for t1:column-name set up; an if statement can be put in to deal with the remaining information.
foreach ($_POST as $key as val) {
// This will result in keys_t1 = key and vals_t1 = val.
 if (preg_match('/^(\w.+):(\w.+)$/', $key, $t_key)) {
  ${"keys_".$t_key[1]} = "$t_key[2], ";
  ${"vals_".$t_key[1]} = "$var, ";
 }
}

// Assume $tables array, containing tables for THIS insert.
foreach ($tables AS $table) {
 $keys_strip = substr(${"keys_".$table}, 0, -2);
 $vals_strip = substr(${"vals_".$table}, 0, -2);
 $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table ($keys_strip) VALUES ($vals_strip)");
}
```

Some tooling might be required to get this to work right, but it should get you to where you need to go. Mind the fact that this will only `INSERT` form-based information. If there's anything you need... well... I strongly recommend using a hidden input type.